# Why most of time ads don't show and Log Console says Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): ( "com.google.DummyAdapter" )?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

My navigation based application experiences a problem while loading ads within   pushed ViewControllers. Error I get in console log is:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): (
>       "com.google.DummyAdapter" ). Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags'
>   setting of your build target.

It also gets called the delegate `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` and the error is:

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=9 "Request Error: No ad to show from
>   all configured ad networks."

The problem is that in the `RootViewController` there is no problem showing ads. I receive 100% ads here but in child viewcontroller only sometimes.

Any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: are you using admob only or another ad network too?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Admob only

Comment: ohk, i've implemented HeyZap network in many apps and also i'm facing same. but this is in simulator only when my app is live and the ads are also not in test mode there is no problem with this.

Comment: Heyzap is collection of many ad networks included AdMob

Comment: I am using Google Admob. Latest version

Comment: have you set -ObjC in linker flags?

Comment: yes. My problem is that in childs viewcontroller, ads won't appear. In root they do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88567/discussion-between-chetan-prajapati-and-silviu-st).